# How do I return this query in blade view

Tags: laravel

```
$semester01 = '1';
    $session01 = '5';
    $level01 = '200';


    $results = DB::table('results')
    ->join('departments', 'results.DepartmentID', '=', 'departments.DepartmantID')
    ->join('subjects', 'results.SubjectID', '=', 'subjects.SubjectID')
    ->groupBy('matricno')
    ->selectRaw('results.matricno as matricno, sum(tnu) as sum, sum(subjects.SubjectValue) as sum2')
    ->where('results.Level', $level01)
    ->where('results.Semester', $semester01)
    ->where('results.SessionID', $session01)
    ->where('departments.DepartmantID', '17')
    ->get();




    //return $arrayed;
    $results2 = DB::table('results')
    ->join('departments', 'results.DepartmentID', '=', 'departments.DepartmantID')
    ->join('subjects', 'results.SubjectID', '=', 'subjects.SubjectID')
    ->groupBy('matricno')
    ->selectRaw('results.matricno as matricno, sum(tnu) as sumr2, sum(subjects.SubjectValue) as sum2r2')
    ->where('results.Level', $level01)
    ->where('results.Semester', $semester01)
    ->where('results.SessionID', $session01)
    ->where('departments.DepartmantID', '7')
    ->get();
```

The above code is supposed to return a group of students with distinct results alongside the various departments.

Result1 and result2 are supposed to be joined together, with matricno being the distinct field. I want to display the result in this form. Merging both results into one tabular form.

matricno | sum | sum2 | sumr2 | sum2r2

Comment: nothing to understand , plz describe want you want

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi Just edited my question

Comment: you tell as you want merge both result  and showing in table

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi, the question was indeed a bit confusing, but i finally figured how to join the table with itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge()` method for merge those collections like;

$merged_result = $results->merge($results2)

Comment: Thanks @Hasan tingir, i finally figured out why i wasn't getting the expected result. I used the collection where method.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a view with some data as follows

```
return view('viewname', ['results' => $results, 'results2' => $results2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('yourview')->with(['results' => $results, 'results2' => $results2]);
```